# Attribute Table is empty

Tags: arcobjects, layers, c#, attribute-table

I am trying to point all layers in MXD files to a different database server. Databse server is Oracle type. Most of the layers consist of views. After changing the datasource programatically for all layers, when I try to open attribute table for layer, attribute table is empty. But if I save MXD and open it in ArcMap, I can see data in attribute table. I tried below code but it didn't work.

```
                ITableWindow pTableWindow = new TableWindowClass();
                pTableWindow.Application = ArcMap.Application;
                ITableWindow3 pTableWindow3 = pTableWindow as ITableWindow3;
                ISet pTableSet = new SetClass();
                pTableWindow3.FindOpenTableWindows(out pTableSet);

                pTableSet.Reset();
                ITableWindow pTableWindowTemp = pTableSet.Next() as ITableWindow;

                while (pTableWindowTemp != null)
                {
                    pTableWindowTemp.Refresh();
                    pTableWindowTemp = pTableSet.Next() as ITableWindow;
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried IContentsView.Refresh? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000005s000000 do you have the tables open in your document? Are you running this from Catalog or Map? It's not clear from you snippet.

Comment: When you pointed to different datasets did you call `IDataLayer2.Disconnect` and then `IDataLayer2.Connect` after assiging a new `DatasourceName?` Doing this is sometimes helps notify things (like table windows) that they need to refresh.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, /**Code Start***/ string queryClassName = "";
                    sw.CheckDatasetName(mapLayer.Name, qd, out queryClassName); IFeatureClass newFc = sw.OpenQueryClass(queryClassName, qd) as IFeatureClass;  
                    (mapLayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass = newFc;
                    mxDoc.UpdateContents();                    
                    mxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh();   /*** Code Ends***/ This is what i did in code to update layer

Comment: Try mxDoc.ContentsView.Refresh() after updating, this will update the TOC and should fire the updates to your tables. It is always preferable to edit your code into your question, it's very hard to read all jumbled up in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I guess your code is not valid in c#. Look at the link below.
 [link] http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriArcMapUI/IMxDocument_ContentsView.htm

Comment: It's one of those get_ or Object_2 interfaces because C# doesn't let you have a get/set parameter.. mxDoc.get_ContentsView(0).Refresh() and also mxDoc.get_ContentsView(1).Refresh() see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000095000000

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I tried mxDoc.get_ContentsView(0).Refresh(null) and mxDoc.get_ContentsView(1).Refresh(null); still no data in attribute table. Refresh function accepts parameter of type Object so i passed null. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, perhaps http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000002r000000 might offer some new insights.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I understand. Thank you so much for taking out time to help me out. I have been trying from past two days and it seems like i have no idea how i can achieve this. So let me see if i get lucky while i am try for some more time.